# Where can i find icon fonts for currency symbols?

Tags: fonts, icon, web-fonts, resource-recommendations

I would like help to finding an icon font package like ionicon for most, if not all, the currency symbols in the world. I currently use ionicon for my kivy app just need the currency symbols now.

Comment: Is there any reason you want an *icon* font as opposed to a font that includes all the currency symbols you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list of fonts that support the Unicode [Currency Symbols Block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/currency_symbols/images.htm), which contains currency symbols not part of more general blocks (i.e. [Basic Latin](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/images.htm) that contains `$` or [Latin-1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/images.htm) that contains `£`) can be found here:

- [Font Support for Unicode Block 'Currency Symbols'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/currency_symbols/fontsupport.htm)

A list of all unicode currency symbols can be seen [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm)—from which you can see which blocks contain each symbol and fonts that support those blocks.

---

If you do for some reason want to use an icon font, Font Awesome has a number of currency symbols, which you can find here:

- [Font Awesome Currency Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&c=currency)

Answer (score 2):

It's sensible to use characters, not a font. What if the font doesn't work somewhere?

This caught my grandmother out when she wrote her book. She used a font for hebrew characters, and this font didn't print out - so some random letters were used instead.

Instead, you should use the unicode characters. [This page has them all](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm), and a selection are below:

```
U+0024  DOLLAR SIGN     $
U+00A2  CENT SIGN       ¢
U+00A3  POUND SIGN      £
U+00A4  CURRENCY SIGN   ¤
U+00A5  YEN SIGN        ¥
```

Comment: But not every font supports all Unicode characters. See the link in [CAI's answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69576/41100) for more info.

Comment: Why do you mean by "character", if not something rendered using a font? You still need a font to display Unicode code points.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use ASCII or Unicode, because this fonts or character are already built-in in most of the operating systems that we have today and it has a standard so you don't have problem rendering them in most software you are using.

Unicode is a way that a user can insert special characters on a computer and we are doing it even in applications like Microsoft Office.

You can find how to use it in this link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input

And the complete list can be found here also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: But not every font supports all Unicode characters. See the link in [CAI's answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69576/41100) for more info.

Comment: Your Welcome...